# Know the location of temporary folder with unzipped archives using ZIPFILE while using WITH on Python

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-zipfile

I want to read a '.accdb' archive that is temporary unzipped using ZIPFILE on Python but the problem is that PYODBC(Library on Python to read .accdb ) requires a PATH to read 'cmg22.accdb and I can't find that path when I unzip the file temporary using **ZipFile.open()**

```
            with zipfile.ZipFile(directorio+archivo,mode='r') as archive:
                zfiledata=BytesIO(archive.read('03 Bases de Datos/01 Balance Físico/'+'cmg'+str(ano_archivo[2:4]+str(mes_archivo))+'.zip'))

                with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as archive2:
                    archivo_cmg='cmg'+str(ano_archivo[2:4]+str(mes_archivo))+'.accdb'
                    archivo_cmg_leer=archive2.open(archivo_cmg)

                    texto_coneccion="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+str(archivo_cmg)+';'
                    conn=pyodbc.connect(texto_coneccion)
                    cursor=conn.cursor()
                    cursor.execute(str(statement))
                    resultado=cursor.fetchall()
                    print(resultado)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\run.py", line 3, in <module>
    funciones.LeerArchivos('BasesdeDatos')
  File "d:\funciones.py", line 83, in LeerArchivos
    conn=pyodbc.connect(texto_coneccion)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] No es un nombre de archivo válido. (-1044) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][Controlador ODBC Microsoft Access] No es un nombre de archivo válido. (-1044)')
PS D:\>
```

I think that I get the error because to connect .ACCDB, I need to give a path of the DB on the connection, and when I use **ZipFile.read()** I don't have that path.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was unzip the needed file in a known directory, and then remove with the **shutil.rmtree(directory)** . For some reason, the Access Driver works only with the file inside a directory. /

The next example didn't work for me:

```
texto_coneccion="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+'file.accdb'+';'
```

But, if you put the file inside a directory, it works well.

```
texto_coneccion="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+'directory/file.accdb'+';'
```

It's weird but this is my solution. Have a good day!